# BLE with MiBand 3

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my first time asking so please forgive if I happen to show mistakes.

Simply put, I want to create app that able to interact with Mi Band 3. The interaction I'm able to make is just reading battery info. What I truly want is enabling the real-time heart rate and steps scan.

What have I done before?

- I've seen and tried https://github.com/pangliang/miband-sdk-android . It was actually this library that made me think that enabling heart scan from Android is possible to do. I tried following with my Mi Band 3 but failed: setHeartRateScanListener, startHeartRateScan, getBatteryInfo.
- I've seen, cloned, and tampered a little with https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge . It is amazing, It can interact with my Mi Band 3, but the problem is Gadgetbridge do not have heart rate scan feature and I kinda overwhelmed with the code.
- Of course, I've tried https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le . After reading the Pangliang's and Gadgetbridge's code I did following to do heart rate scan.

First, I know that I should put listener right? So here's the function

```
    public void listenHeartRate() {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        descriptor.setValue(new byte[] {0x01, 0x00});
        if(!bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "tesListenHeartRate: failed");

        }
    }
```

And then, I start the scanning with this.

```
    public void startHeartRate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "tesHeartRate: start");
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = bluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")).getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a39-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{21, 2, 1});
        if (!bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "tesStartHeartRate: failed");
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that writeCharacteristic always returning status 3 which means GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED.

So, where did I go wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: This looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731701/android-ble-write-oncharacteristicwrite-returns-status-gatt-write-not-permitte

Comment: thank you . but I've checked that question before. and I still didn't find any solution back then. maybe I'll just redoing that again.

Answer (score 1):

"(...) I nearly gave up, but then realized that I was missing out something. Authentication. Yes, I missed authentication! Thanks to Andrey Nikishaev,
He has explained very well how mi band is being paired and authenticated. That gave me a good head start. And here are the Authentication steps: (...)"

Whole article: https://medium.com/@yogeshojha/i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-3-and-here-is-how-i-did-it-43d68c272391